# SharePoint 2013 : greyed a child form

Tags: sharepoint

I work with SharePoint 2013. I have a list which contains "cars" and each listitem corresponds to a car.

In this list, when I click on an item to show its fields it opens in the `dispForm.aspx`.

In the `dispForm`, I have an "History" button to open a second pop-up/frame to show the modifications that were made on it.

The problem : when i open the `dispForm`, I click the "History" button to show the next pop-up , I can close the parent form and the children pop-up stay and can not be closed...

I know that these two popup are SharePoint-native and I wonder how can I tell the parent pop-up to greyed when the child one is opened OR at least close the child when the parent is closed?

Comment: How are you including the History button on the display form? Would you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48667375/edit) your question to include the modifications to the display form that you have made?

Comment: I am doing TMA for my client and i have to fix this for him. I didn't made this inclusion unfortunaly :(
I think that it is a call to the native form : Versions.aspx

Comment: I think that the "History" button is standard and appears when the versionning of the item is activated